# Forcefully Stop Recursion in PHP

Tags: php, session, recursion

This is my function to store navbar into session

```
function menu($sp_id,$offset = 0, $ulclass, $liclass) {
        $menudb =new db;

        if($offset == 0)
            $_SESSION['nav_menu'].= "<ul class=\"sf-menu\">";

        if($sp_id == 0)
        {
            $sql = "SELECT `label`, `link` , `sp_id` FROM `nav_menu` ORDER BY `sort` ASC LIMIT $offset,100000000000000";
            $menudb->query($sql);

            while ($row = $menudb->result()->fetch_assoc()) {
                $offset++;
                $_SESSION['nav_menu'].= "<li class=\"$liclass\"><a href='" . $row['link'] . "'>" . $row['label'] . "</a>";

                if($row['sp_id'] != 0){
                    $_SESSION['nav_menu'].= "<div class=\"mobnav-subarrow\"></div>";
                     menu($row['sp_id'],$offset, $ulclass, $liclass);
                }
                else
                    $_SESSION['nav_menu'].="</li>";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $sql = "SELECT `bt_name` AS label FROM `business_sub_type` WHERE `sp_id` = $sp_id OR `sp_id` = 0";
            $menudb->query($sql);

            $_SESSION['nav_menu'].= "<ul class=\"sf-menu\">";

            while ($row = $menudb->result()->fetch_assoc()) {
                $_SESSION['nav_menu'].= "<li class=\"$liclass\"><a href='#'>" . $row['label'] . "</a></li>";
            }
            $_SESSION['nav_menu'].= "</ul></li>";
            menu(0,$offset, $ulclass, $liclass);
        }
        $_SESSION['nav_menu'].= "</ul>";
//here
}
```

Now i want my function should die at any cost at //here whenever it comes at /here .But it repeats itself and session store menu again and again,

And please also guide me if this is the right way to decrease your load time by saving menu into session? Thanks

Comment: Can you show us how you call your function initially please? What parameters you use?

Comment: It seems to me that you should not call menu(0,$offset, $ulclass, $liclass); inside the else part. This way you will stop the recursion once you display the 'business_sub_type' of a particular 'nav_menu'. I may be wrong as I do not have your DB scheme.

Comment: @YasenZhelev firstly i call function 'menu(0,0,'ul-menu','li-menu')';
And let me clear one thing
`sp_id` is a foreign key of `nav_menu` in `business_sub_type` So if a `nav_menu`.`sp_id` has none zero value it means that it must have childs in `business_sub_type`

Comment: And @YasenZhelev I can't because i need to get all menu names!

Comment: you should be getting them from this query already $sql = "SELECT `label`, `link` , `sp_id` FROM `nav_menu` ORDER BY `sort` ASC LIMIT $offset,100000000000000";

Comment: If that is possible please let me know. As i was unable to figure how can i make hierarchy with a single query like
<ul>
<li>
a
</li>
<li>
b
<div class="chile"></div>
<ul>
<li>
bb
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You even do not need recursion for what you are doing. If you had a multi-tier DB structure with depth not being set initially you should use recursion. In your case you seem to have only two levels: 'nav_menu' DB table and 'business_sub_type' DB table that is related to the first one. All you have to do is cycle through the 'nav_menu' and for every one of them cycle through the 'business_sub_type's related to it.

Just change your function to something like that

```
function menu() {
    $menudb =new db;
    $submenu = new db;
    $_SESSION['nav_menu'] = "<ul class=\"sf-menu\">";
    // get all nav_menu items ordered by 'sort' column
    $sql = "SELECT `label`, `link` , `sp_id` FROM `nav_menu` ORDER BY `sort` ASC";
    $menudb->query($sql);
    while ($row = $menudb->result()->fetch_assoc()) {
        $_SESSION['nav_menu'].= "<li class=\"li-menu\"><a href='" . $row['link'] . "'>" . $row['label'] . "</a>";

        if($row['sp_id'] != 0){
            $_SESSION['nav_menu'].= "<div class=\"mobnav-subarrow\"></div>";
            // get all 'business_sub_type' for this nam_menu
            $sql = "SELECT `bt_name` AS label FROM `business_sub_type` WHERE `sp_id` = ".$row['sp_id']." OR `sp_id` = 0";
            // I am not sure the ' OR `sp_id` = 0' part is correct at all 
            $submenu->query($sql);
            $_SESSION['nav_menu'].= "<ul class=\"sf-menu\">";
            while ($row1 = $submenu->result()->fetch_assoc()) {
                $_SESSION['nav_menu'].= "<li class=\"li-menu\"><a href='#'>" . $row1['label'] . "</a></li>";
            }
            $_SESSION['nav_menu'].="</ul></li>";
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['nav_menu'].="</li>";
        }
    }

    $_SESSION['nav_menu'].= "</ul>";
}
```

And to answer the question about the recursion. You stop the recursion by not calling it inside itself. Or in other words, define a logical branch in which you do not self-call the recursion function if certain conditions are not met or are met.

Comment: Thanks mate, Its working like charm which i didn't think about :P Well i just made a little change and its working, Thanks :)